# How can I share the value of a property from one tab screen to another using a shared VM?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application with two screens. There's a button to change theme on one screen and I want that value to be noticed on the other screen.  Here's what I have:

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    string _theme;
    public string Theme { get => _theme; set => SetProperty(ref _theme, value); }
}

public partial class SettingsTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ }

public partial class HomeTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ }
```

My settings screen is bound to the Settings VM and I change the value like this:

```
`vm.Theme = "X";`
```

I check this using at a debug point and I can see the BaseViewModel has changed.

My home screen is bound to the Home VM and I try to observe the value like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Theme}" />
```

I check this using at a debug point in the OnAppearing and I can see the BaseViewModel has **not** changed.

Note that the VMs are pretty big and everything else is working. Also the setProperty method is used very many times and works but the problem I have is just for the shared VM parameter `Theme`.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening? It's like I look at the two VM bases and they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your ViewModels create their own instance of your BaseViewModel. So basically you have the BaseViewModel two times in your memory and they don't share anything!

You could solve your problem when you could use the Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter. In both ViewModels you subscribe to a "ThemeChanged" message, and when you change the theme, you send your "ThemeChanged" method.

Or as an alternative you use only one ViewModel for your TabPages (but as you wrote your VMs are very complex, it is not the best option)